# Count number of data points in file

Tags: command-line, bash

I am currently struggling with something simple such as counting, the number of datapoints there is in this [file](http://pastebin.com/avkXMgCE).

Each datapoint is seperated with an space.. How do i using the cli in linux count the number of values this file contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by

```
cat file | wc -w
```

or

```
wc -w file
```

"file" is your file name.

Comment: god dammit.. wordcount.. ofcourse..